# Is there a mudra associated with renouncement?

Tags: mudra

For meditation purpose, and for appeasing suffering, I think I need a symbol associated with renouncement.

Is there a mudra that would particularly fit with this idea ?
Or a symbol that would come to your mind ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there's one called the *[shramanamudrâ](https://www.google.com/search?q=shramanamudr%C3%A2)* (see also [Śramaṇa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9Arama%E1%B9%87a)).